# WebSphere + Simple HTTPS Post = SocketException

Tags: java, http, ssl, websphere

This is about as basic as I can make it - brand new setup in RAD, brand new project, all default settings and this code:

```
        try {
        String url = "https://www.verisign.com";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        PostMethod post = new PostMethod(url);
        client.executeMethod(post);
        String response2 = post.getResponseBodyAsString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

This is the error I get (not very informative imho)

```
    java.net.SocketException
at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:5)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:93)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:651)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:628)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:497)
```

Any ideas on what I could try to get a more descriptive error?

*UPDATE*

When I look in "runtimes\base_v61\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc" I find this error getting printed to the logs:

```
com.ibm.websphere.ssl.SSLException: java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=127, too big.
at com.ibm.websphere.ssl.JSSEHelper.getSSLSocketFactory(JSSEHelper.java:583)
at com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory.<init>(SSLSocketFactory.java:87)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1243)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:9)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:93)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:651)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:628)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:497)
```

*UPDATE - With the answer*
FIXED, that was a fun issue, here's how you resolve it (if you ever come across it)

Step 1: Launch ikeyman.exe in \SDP70\jdk\jre\bin

Step 2: Open your certs file in SDP70\runtimes\base_v61\java\jre\lib\security (for example, mine is cacerts)

Step 3: Enter in your password (do you remember your password)?

Step 4: IF THE DATABASE TYPE IS NOT PKS12 CONTINUE

Step 5: Save your cert file as pks12

Step 6: Stop Websphere

Step 7: Rename your old cert file to something like "cacerts.bak" rename your new PKS12 certs file to be the default

Step 8: Restart websphere, get legitimate error

Step 9: Profit

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the information and stack of the exceptions that caused this exception (the "inner" exceptions). printStackTrace() will not print these out.

Either use a proper logging framework (like log4j or slf4j) that does this for you, or you can do it manually.

```
e.printStackTrace();
Throwable cause = e.getCause();
while (cause != null) {
    cause.printStackTrace();
    cause = cause.getCause();
}
```

Comment: Hey pap, thanks for the quick reply, unfortunately that is as deep as the rabbit hole goes. e.getCause() returns null on the first request and never enters the while statement.

Comment: What does toString() give on the exception?